# returning an std::optional<Type>& reference where Type is an abstract class

Tags: c++, c++-templates

Background: I have a `City` template class that contains a 2D array that is populated by types that conform to `ISpecies` abstract class. The grid can be any size.
code:
ISpecies

```cpp
class ISpecies {
public:
    ISpecies() = default;
    virtual ~ISpecies() = default;
    virtual std::string toString() = 0;
    virtual void move() = 0;
    virtual void spawn() = 0;
};
```

City

```cpp
template<int H = 20, int W = 20>
class City {
protected:
    int h = H;
    int w = W;
    ISpecies* grid[H][W];


public:
    City() = default;
    City(City&) = delete;
    City(City&&) noexcept = default;
    City& operator=(const City&) = delete;
    City& operator=(City&&) noexcept = delete;
    ~City() = default;

    /** getters and setter methods */
    std::optional<ISpecies>& getOrganism(int x, int y);
    int getHeight() const;
    int getWidth() const;
    void setOrganism(ISpecies& species, int x, int y);

    /** stream output for printing out the city grid */
    template<int _h, int _w>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const City<_h, _w>& city);

};
```

Im having some problems with this getter function.
I have this getter where I am returning an optional reference of an abstract class:

```cpp
template<int H, int W>
std::optional<ISpecies>& City<H, W>::getOrganism(int x, int y) {
    if((x < 0) || (x > this->w) || (y < 0) || (y > this->w)) {
        return std::nullopt;
    } else {
        return this->grid[y][x];
    }
};
```

However I am getting an error at `std::nullopt` where `Non-const lvalue reference to type 'std::optional<ISpecies>' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'const nullopt_t'`.

I am wondering if there is any way I can fix this? I have tried simply returning `std::optional<ISpecies>` however, I receive an error where I am returning an abstract class.

Thank you kindly for the help!

Comment: You can't have a `std::optional<ISpecies>`, because `ISpecies` is abstract, and even if it were not, it would slice. Instead, you can return the pointer and check for `nullptr` (which you should initialize your `grid` array to).

Comment: Oh you're right, I forgot about slicing, I changed it to std::optional<ISpecies*> as @eerorika suggested and that seems to make sense to me

Comment: @I.C.Wiener `std::optional<ISpecies*>` makes no sense, though. Just return `ISpecies*` instead. Either a grid cell is holding `nullptr` or it is not. You don't need `optional` to differentiate when an `ISpecies*` pointer **doesn't exist** versus when the pointer **is set to `nullptr`**, do you? That is rarely ever needed when dealing with pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minimal change to make the example well-formed would be to change the return type of `getOrganism` to `std::optional<ISpecies*>`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an optional reference type, you can use `std::reference_wrapper`. With this, your code looks something like this:

```
template<int H, int W>
std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<ISpecies>>
City<H, W>::getOrganism(int x, int y) {
    if((x < 0) || (x > this->w) || (y < 0) || (y > this->w)) {
        return std::nullopt;
    } else {
        return this->grid[y][x];
    }
};
```

Your retrieval code would look like:

```
auto org = getOrganism(x, y);
if (org.has_value())
    std::cout << org.value().get().toString() << '\n';
else
    std::cout << "No organism there.\n";
```

This gets you a little closer to an optional reference (as opposed to your reference to an optional).

Comment: I was just going to suggest this as another solution to the problem.

Comment: `org.value().get().toString()` can be simplified a little to `org->get().toString()`, or re-written as `static_cast<ISpecies&>(*org).toString()`